# About, tag questions, "She likes nobody, does she?" or "She likes nobody, doesn't she?"

Tags: word-usage, tag-questions

[This site](http://www.grammar.cl/Intermediate/Question_Tags.htm) says

Statements using "**Nobody, none, nothing...**" are treated as negative sentences.

Ex: **Nobody likes her, do they?**

That is when "**nobody**" is the subject.

What bout when "**nobody**" is the object.

"**She likes nobody, does she?**" or "**She likes nobody, doesn't she?**"

**Note**: things are much easier if we use "**anybody**"

**She doesn't like anybody, does she?**

Comment: Native speakers don't normally say "She likes nobody".  Instead we negate the positive "She doesn't like anybody".   I suppose it's *grammatical* to use  "nobody" as the object, but of your two sentences neither sounds right.  If forced to pick I'd go with "She likes nobody, doesn't she?"  but it still sounds awkward.

Comment: "She likes nobody, no?" could be used if one must compress the sentence as much as possible while retaining the meaning. Otherwise, "She doesn't like anybody, does she?" sounds the most natural.

Comment: Personally, I would choose "She like nobody, doesn't she?"
But I think it'd be better to say "She doesn't like anybody"

Answer (score 1):

Both “does she?” and “doesn't she?” are in some way wrong, so the tag question is best avoided altogether.

Saying "She likes nobody, does she?" is poor English because the tag question doesn't negate the verb. Saying "She likes nobody, doesn't she?" is poor English as it uses a double negative: the tag question is equivalent to "Doesn't she like nobody?", which is poor style, and may be ambiguous.

Since the tag question is basically asking for agreement you can say "She likes nobody. What do you reckon?" But this is longer and more awkward.

Fortunately there is an equivalent expression which allows for easy formation of tag questions: "She doesn't like anybody, does she?" This is what I'd expect most speakers to say.