# Using "they" in tag questions with everybody/nobody etc

Tags: tag-questions

When you want to add a tag question to "There is nobody in the garden." would it be "are they"?

I just have read before that in tag questions we use (they) when the question include everybody/nobody etc.

Comment: ***There is*** nobody, is there?

Comment: *Nobody has answered this question, **have they**?*

Comment: Related: [About, tag questions, “She likes nobody, does she?” or “She likes nobody, doesn't she?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/146237/about-tag-questions-she-likes-nobody-does-she-or-she-likes-nobody-doesn/146364#146364) and [“Nothing is available, is anything?” Tag questions for negative sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85106/nothing-is-available-is-anything-tag-questions-for-negative-sentences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sentence that begins with ***There is*** is called an *existential clause*, the sentence refers to the existence or presence of something.

> In English, existential clauses usually use [the **dummy subject** construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause#Formation_of_existential_clauses) (also known as expletive) with *there*, as in "There are boys in the yard"…

In the OP's sentence, **the subject** is not "nobody" but *there (is)*. Consequently, the rule dictates that you should repeat the same subject used in the clause to make a question tag.

> **There is** nobody in the garden, ***is there***?

As illustrated by FumbleFinger's [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163663/question-about-question-tag-nobody-everybody/163669#comment327411_163663), when the main clause begins with the subject "nobody", or "everybody", "everyone", "no one", etc. THEY, also called the [**singular *they***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they),  is used in the question tag.

> ***Nobody*** is in the garden, are ***they***?

The pronoun *nobody* makes the clause negative, so the verb used in question tag should be positive. However, if the pronoun *everybody/everyone* is used, the question tag should be in the negative.

> Everybody **is** in the garden, **aren't** they?

Wikipedia explains that the *singular they* is used with the following pronouns: *someone*, *anybody*, *everybody*, *everyone*, *nobody* and *no one*. Even though these pronouns are singular, native speakers prefer to use the genderless "they" in question tags while  Wikipedia argues these pronouns:

> have an "implied plurality" that is somewhat similar to the implied plurality of collective or group nouns such as crowd or team, and in some sentences where the antecedent is one of these "implied plural" pronouns, the word they cannot be replaced by generic *he*, suggesting a "notional plural" […].

and provides the following examples

> - “**Everybody** was crouched behind the furniture to surprise me, and *they* tried to. But I already knew *they* were there.”
> - “**Nobody** was late, were *they*?”