# Subject pronoun of 'everyone' in tag question

Tags: grammatical-number, tag-questions, subject-pronouns

The word **everyone** is a singular indefinite pronoun. But while tagging, why its subject pronoun is **they** which is plural?
e.g.

> Everyone wants to live, **don't they?**

Here, in the statement, the subject **'everyone'** is a singular pronoun and it has used a singular verb **'wants'**. But in the question part, the word **'they'** is the subject pronoun of 'everyone' which is plural.

***Why? Please explain.***

*This question is not a duplicate of [Using "they" in tag questions with everybody / nobody etc.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163663/using-they-in-tag-questions-with-everybody-nobody-etc) Because I want to know the reason of using plural subject pronoun in the case of singular pronoun as a subject in the statement.*

Comment: I can just about get my head around *Everyone is here, **isn't he**?* for a tag question, but it sounds clunky compared to ***...aren't they**?* I have to say that second version feels more like an example of "singular **they**" to me, but I don't know whether that's part of the "explanation" being sought here.

Comment: I expanded my original answer and added a notable reference in: [Using "they" in tag questions with everybody/nobody etc](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163663/using-they-in-tag-questions-with-everybody-nobody-etc)

Comment: There's probably a historic reason for it, but not a rule-based one where you could derive "aren't they" as the correct choice. Many other tag questions ignore the common rules of English, like, "I'm a teacher, **aren't** I?" where you would naturally expect "... ***amn't** I". They simply have to be memorized.

Answer (score 2):

The pronoun "they" is grammatically plural even when it denotes a single person (like it does in some general statements or if the person's gender is unknown - so-called "singular they"). They are, they do, they go, they write, etc.

Since a statement using "everyone", such as "everyone wants to live", is a general statement that applies to both men and women, you won't say either "he" or "she" in the tag but "they", which is neutral about their gender. (See what I did there at the end of that sentence?)

Singular they also comes in handy when you simply don't know what gender the person you're dealing with is:
"Nickname123 made this comment on my blog. I think they're wrong."

Comment: I don't think gender is relevant here. The syntactic properties of the compound determinative "everyone" determine the agreement.

Comment: It's kind of the reason behind those syntactic properties. I find getting the underlying logic (if there is any, but in this case we're lucky because there is) more helpful to understanding things than just memorising "because-I-said-so" rules.

Comment: The prnoun _they_ is **not** grammatically plural in this context, any more than the pronoun _you_ is "grammatically plural" when it refers to one person.

Comment: @BillJ this "they" is a third person singular pronoun that is neutral between masculine and feminine. (as written in section 10.50 of Quirk et al on page no 770)

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes, but that's not why "they" is being used here. "Everyone" implies a plural set, and it's this that motivates plural "they" in the tag.

Comment: @BillJ *nods* that was my opinion about it as well. But in that section I came across a sentence something like this: "Everyone thinks he has the answer." It sais "he" is more formal. But now this "they" is also common in place of "he". In OP's sentence it is also correct: "Everyone wants to live, doesn't he?"